# Accessing variables from prototype-defined functions

Tags: javascript, prototype, private-methods, public-method, private-functions

Lets say I have this function, I am trying to get values of value1 and 2 , what’s the right way to do it.
1. how do I make value 1 and value 2 defined , when it exits the function 
2. how do i get the value in another function without calling “doSomething” function

```
test.prototype.doSomething = function (){
    test = new Execution(experiment);

    function experiment(bla) {
        forEach(function(bla) {
            var value1 = bla.value1;
            var value2 = bla.balue2;
            console.log(value1); //defined 
        });
        console.log(value1); //undefined 
    }
    console.log(value1); //undefined
}

test.prototype.testSomething = function() {
    var testSomething = values1;

}
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The way you have those values defined the answer is: "you don't". The question is why are you doing things in this way? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You don't. These aren't "private" variables, they're just scoped, and they're marked for garbage collection as soon as the innermost function exits, since they're no longer in scope after that.

Comment: What are `Experiment`, `forEach` and `test`? Why does `doSomething` overwrite `test`? How are `testSometing` and `doSomething` called in the first place? Where do you want to get which particular value?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by declaring value1 and value2 out of experiment function and assign value to those variable within the function. Below is code:

```
test.prototype.doSomething = function (){
var value1, value2;
test = new Execution(experiment);
function experiment(bla) {
    forEach(function(bla) 
        value1 = bla.value1;
        value2 = bla.balue2;
        console.log(value1);  
    });
    console.log(value1); 
}
console.log(value1);
```

}

Comment: Please do not propose this "solution" without stating all the important drawbacks.